# How to use clang++ with -std=c++11 -Weverything -Werror

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, clang, compiler-warnings

I want to compile the following file (temp.cpp):

```
#include <iostream> 

class Foo {
public:
  Foo() = default;
};

int main(){
  std::cout << "Works!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

With the following command: `clang++ temp.cpp -o temp -std=c++11 -Weverything -Werror`

There is an error:

> temp.cpp:5:11: error: defaulted function definitions are incompatible with C++98 [-Werror,-Wc++98-compat]

I understand that there is a warning like c++98-compat and it is part of everything. How can I enable all warnings except c++98-compat? Is there a c++11 compatible flag for -Weverything?

Comment: Add `-Wno-c++98-compat`, but I don't know if there's a generic way.

Comment: @Mat Can you please post this as an answear so I can accept it.

Comment: `Weverything` enables all the warning, it has nothing to do with C++98, try `-Wall` and/or `-Wextra`

Comment: I have no idea if that is enough to have a "c++11 compatible flag for -Weverything" as you ask for.

Comment: as user1824407 said -Wall works just fine. Don't use `-Weverything`.

Comment: I want all the warnings, which are not against c++11. So I want Weverything. Using just Wall is not an option.

Comment: This is why I say `-Weverything -Werror` is stupid. It makes perfectly valid code fail for spurious reasons. You insist you want all warnings as errors, but you don't really want all of them.  If you insist on doing this then as @Mat said turn off the specific errors you don't want with `-Wno-xxx`

Comment: @JonathanWakely You can say that without calling names on people, you know?

Comment: @JohanBoulé where did I call anybody names? I said the combination of compiler options is stupid. That's not a person.

Comment: @JonathanWakely That was 10 years ago, so maybe you know how to better "tone" you words now. AFAIK `-Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Werror` works as intended by the OP and may make sense in his particular context, that's about it, I don't want to know if it's a "stupid thing to insist doing".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Actually, you probably do not want all the warnings, because a number of warnings can be considered as being stylistic or subjective and others (such as the one you ran afoul of) are just stupid in your situation.

`-Weverything` was initially built for two reasons:

- discovery: it's pretty hard otherwise to get a list of all available warnings
- black-listing alternative: with gcc, you cherry pick the warnings you wish to apply (white-listing), with `-Weverything` you cherry pick those you do not wish to apply; the advantage is that when moving over to a new version of the compiler, you are more likely to benefit from new warnings

Obviously, discovery is not really compatible with production use; therefore you seem to fall in the *black-listing* case.

Clang diagnostics system will output (by default) the name of the most specific warning group that is responsible for generating a warning (here `-Wc++98-compat`) and each warning group can be turned off by adding `no-` right after the `-W`.

Therefore, for blacklisting, you get:

```
-Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-...
```

And you are encouraged to revise the list of blacklisted warnings from time to time (for example, when you upgrade to a newer compiler).

Comment: Also -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic, assuming you’re fortunate enough to be able to use GCC_WARN_PEDANTIC = YES.