# Importance of "Lambda expressions are incompatible with C++98"?

Tags: c++, lambda

In compiling this code:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::future<int> result(std::async(
                [](int m, int n) { return m + n; }, 2, 4));

    std::cout << "from main"    << std::endl;
    std::cout << "from asnyc: " << result.get() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

with

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Weverything promises2.cc -o promises2
```

I got the warnings:

```
promises2.cc:6:17: warning: lambda expressions are incompatible with C++98
promises2.cc:5:29: warning: local type '(lambda at promises2.cc:6:17)' as
      template argument is incompatible with C++98
```

These are warnings, but are they supposed to be signal something that might be wrong? Aren't lambdas *supposed* to be incompatible with C++98? What's the surprise that these warnings are supposed to tell me?

Comment: You just enabled **every** warning. Some people want a warning because you may need to compile with older code. So the problem is `-Weverything`

Comment: They just tell you what they tell you: Lambdas didn't exist then. If for some reason at a later time or when re-using code in a different project you are stuck with an old compiler or must compile with compatibility options you cannot compile your program. Not more, not less. (C++ 98 is the first standardized version and as such is a smallest common denominator that all compilers will be able to compile.)

Comment: `-Weverything` warns about, well, everything.  In this case it is warning that your code is not backwards compatible.

Comment: I "get"  the backwards incompatibility argument, but would think that I signalled this intention already by specifically giving the `-std=c++11` option. But if that is all this warning means, then I guess it is basically meaningless.

Comment: @rityzmon It means what it says. What's difficult about that?

Comment: @rityzmon some people care about certain parts of their code being able to compile with old compilers. For them is this warning.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Just that the compiler is warning me of a potential problem that I already told it to not care about. I'm just going to disable that warning and get on with it. Thanks.

Comment: The `-Wall` and `-Wextra` are good flags to have. Maybe even `-Wpedantic` (or just `-pedantic` for GCC compatibility). That will give you all important warnings (and then some). The `-Weverything` is to much, and will give many warnings you in most cases do not need. Of course, you can always disable specific warning flags, but then you would have a *lot* of `-Wno-xxx` flags on your command line, obscuring the important options and flags.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Great alternative. Didn't think of that. Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use clang++ with -std=c++11 -Weverything -Werror](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181789/how-to-use-clang-with-std-c11-weverything-werror)