# static function is used in an inline function with external linkage - while trying to use load instruction inside an inline function

Tags: c, clang, simd, intrinsics, avx512

I was working with clang compiler recently for a work of mine. I encountered the following issue which I didn't encounter either with gcc or msvc compiler

```
test_newer.c:8:32: fatal error: static function '_mm_loadu_epi8' is used in an inline function with external linkage [-Wstatic-in-inline]
            __m128i testing1 = _mm_loadu_epi8(a);
```

The following code snippet replicates the same issue

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

#define __forceinline __attribute__((always_inline)) inline

__forceinline void testing() {
            unsigned char a[16] = {3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 3, 4};
            __m128i testing1 = _mm_loadu_epi8(a);
            printf("Sample print\n");
}

int main() {
    testing();
    return 0;
}
```

This was the command I used to compile the file -

```
clang -march=skylake-avx512 -O2 -c -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wno-reserved-identifier -Weverything -Wfatal-errors test_newer.c -o file1
```

Is there any other alternative for the issue faced while loading while retaining the same flags as used in the command line? Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason that `testing()` isn't `static`? Does making it `static` fix the problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it cant be reproduced https://godbolt.org/z/o49sdG434

Comment: or compilation only emitting the code https://godbolt.org/z/d4PYGW44r

Comment: Any reason you're using `_mm_loadu_epi8` instead of `_mm_loadu_si128` here?  See also [What is the difference between \_mm512\_load\_epi32 and \_mm512\_load\_si512?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53905757)  What clang version are you using that has this problem?  Intrinsics like `_mm_loadu_epi8` shouldn't be defined as `static` in `immintrin.h`.

Comment: Somewhat related question regarding `-Weverything`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181789/how-to-use-clang-with-std-c11-weverything-werror

Comment: Oh, my mistake, on my Arch Linux system (with clang 15), intrinsic functions are declared `static __inline__`.  Did you perhaps `#define __inline__ /* something */` that breaks the headers, so those functions end up declared as `static` but not `inline`? But even that doesn't generate the same error: https://godbolt.org/z/5PTzhhvox  Double-underscore keywords like `__forceinline` and `__inline__` are reserved for the implementation; don't invent your own uses for them, only use stuff like `__attribute__` or `__asm__` to access known extensions.

Comment: Making testing() static helps. But in the original codebase am working on has calls to the function from other files. So am not sure we can apply it there

Comment: _mm_loadu_epi8 avoids casting to __m128i* before usage while _mm_loadu_si128 needs it. Otherwise there is not much difference.  But also tried using that. That also leads to same issues

Comment: Attaching clang version am using for reference : Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1